# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'B' to data type int

Tags: plsql

Getting this error when ever I tried to execute the entire procedure. Below is the piece of code from the procedure.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT SUBSTRING (a.GL06001,19,10)    as ProjectNo, 
    --PR01040 UD_10,
    SUBSTRING (a.GL06001,1,8)       as AccountNo, 
    a.GL06002               as TransNo, 
    a.GL06004               as TransAmount, 
    a.GL06003               as TransDate,
    a.GL06005               as TransDesc,
    'GL'                    as SourceType,
    ' '                 as ResourceCode,
    ' '                     as TransLine,
    0                   as CostPR,
    '000000'                as PRTransNo,
    a.GL06027               as SubprojNo,
    a.GL06028               as ActiLineNo,
    a.GL06012               as TransType,
    a.GL06016               as Counter
     from  ScalaMX.dbo.GL06PA17 a where  a.GL06003 between  '2017-02-21 00:00:00.000' and '2017-03-01 00:00:00.000'
```

There are actually 18000+ rows and 15 columns. Any hint on how to track which column has B value?

I downloaded the result in Excel and ctrl+f 'B' But still no clue and I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

convert into stored procedure, see below sample

```
declare
  n integer;
  m integer;
begin
  for i in ( select primarykeycolumn, a,b from table ) 
   loop
     begin
         n := i.a;
         m := i.b;
     exception
         when others then
            dbms_output.put_line(i.primarykeycolumn);  
     end  
  end loop; 
   end;
```

When conversion error happens it will catch the exception hence find the primary key.